# left and right functions

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use a VBA code for selecting a value that is for example the first or the last value of a series, if this series is located all in one Cell of Excel?

Is there a code using the right or left application that can be implemented?

Comment: Add an example please, and what you've tried? it sounds like the LEFT and RIGHT functions are all you need

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please read Help for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question with the example, to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuccia, the following take the very last character from cell A1 and pastes the value into B1:

```
Cells(1, 2).Value = Right(Range("A1"), 1)
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot... another question...do you know how to modify the settings of VBA in a way that they correspond to the settings of Windows? I have  a problem with the decimal separator because the settings are different...is there a function named "local" for example?

Comment: please can you mark the best answer using the tick to the left. I would advise you ask this question as another question rather than a comment, and check @Ron Rosenfeld comment on creating good questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to concatenate the two values, use `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1),RIGHT(A1,1))` assuming the cell is A1. If you just need them individually, just select what you need from the expression.

Comment: the question is:" I have to keep every day a value situated in a DB. this value is the last of a string. The string is allocated in one cell.How could i use the right function to keep only the last value?